# Do Robo Monkeys do more damage than Sun Gods?

Tags: bloons-td-5

Disregarding the Robo Monkey's ability upgrade, does it do more raw damage than Sun God monkeys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit hard to compute, but I'll try my best.

According to [multiple](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_God) [sources](http://btd-5.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Monkey), a single sun ray from the Sun God will pop 15 balloons.  The Sun God fires 3 streams total.

The Robo Monkey can pop a total of 7 balloons per shot, and shoots twice at the same time.

However, the sunrays diverge somewhat and have a tougher time hitting individual MOAB-class balloons.  They also fire at half the rate of the Robo Monkey's streams.

The Sun God's streams do pierce, however, making them better at clearing out large swaths of balloons at once.

There's a lot of back and forth there, but I'd say the real advantage of the Sun God that makes me pick it almost every time over the Robo Monkey is the ability to turn it into a temple, which makes it obscenely powerful and leaves room for more towers to be placed.

Comment: Suppose you are choosing what to place next to a temple? Would you mix in some robos, so you can do a better job on MOABS, also, for those, only robos can be upgraded to tier 4?

Answer (score 1):

I think sun god because it has a bigger damage, shoots three sun rays and you can turn into a temple you can't stop that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do sun avatar because the next upgrade is OP.

A sun temple is better than 2 sun avatars. It has two airplanes surrounding the temple.

Splash: Yes, Camo: Haven't tried yet but use the monkey village, Single Target: Yep, Fire Rate: Faster than a fortnight SMG

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the robo-monkey since it is much cheaper and sun temple is almost equivalent to the cost of 4 tech terrors. Also if sun temple needs a LOT of sacrifices to be OP, I would choose several tech terrors to avoid not placing anything just to save up to the sun temple. Also since the robo monkeys are good at destroying MOABS and is much cheaper than sun god, I would say the robo monkey is stronger in earlier game I guess.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, robo monkey and sun god are almost the same. They are better at different stages. Robo monkey is good for farming, for single target damage. Sun god is better late-game, when you are doing temples. I get one sun god when farming, to help with bloons if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer appears to have some good information about which is better strategically, but it doesn't appear to answer the question posed (which does more raw damage).

Answer (score 0):

As a rank 67

**Sun God**

Fires three streams a little under every second.
Sun rays are able to pierce and spread out as they go farther off the screen.
(Pierce means destroy more than 1 bloon layer at once.)

**Camo:**  No. Great on regenerating bloons.

**Splash Damage:** Yes.

**Single target:** Not so great.

**Moab-class:** Okay.

---

**Robo Monkey**

Instead of shooting one constant beam like a normal super monkey, has 2 guns that can shoot independently from each other. Guns shoot whatever upgrade you have(lasers, plasma, darts.)

**Camo:** Again, no. Great on regenerating bloons.

**Splash Damage:** Not really...

**Single target:** Definitely. Totally anti-moab.

Here is a little trivia, just to get your mind going.

-A sun god has more popping power than an unmodified temple(although temple has camo detection)due to the fact sun gods fire three rays a little under every second and temples shoot 1 huge wave a little under every 3 seconds(in non fast foward)

-a robo monkey with no path 1 upgrades surprisingly can destroy leads with ease, although a normal super monkey with only darts cannot even dent leads.
-robo monkeys are a reference to the 1987 film robo-cop.
-laser monkeys cannot destroy leads.

**Here is my final answer:**
sun gods will clear bloons with ease, so sun gods are better for taking out massive waves of bloons, however;
robo monkeys are better against moab-class bloons, due to the fact they are better-suited for single target combat.
So, you should definitely get a balance between the two tier 3s. Here is the ratio I use:
5:1(for every 5th robo monkey I get 1 sun god)

Comment: Pierce does not mean destroying more than one layer at once.  That would be popping power.  Pierce means hitting more than one bloon.  A "standard" projectile hits one bloon and stops.  Weapons with pierce can pierce through the first bloon and hit additional bloons behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Robo Monkeys can dent several BFBS to nothing while the Sun God leaves some of them laying around into cermaics or zebras. A robo monkey can dent a ZOMG much better than the Sun God. The Robo Monkey is 3/5 the cost of Sun Gods, so you can have several robo monkeys instead of getting a few Sun Gods.